# Save attachment in Outlook using VBA on secondary Inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I have been trying to get below to trigger on a shared inbox.

I can get this working fine using a script I call manually with a for loop on the Inbox.

I can also get this working using my main inbox using the `Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items`.

Any help on where I am going wrong?

```
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim olInboxItems As MAPIFolder
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objOwner = ns.CreateRecipient("xx@xx.com")
    Set olInboxItems = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
    Debug.Print ns
    Debug.Print objOwner
    Debug.Print olInboxItems
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim olMailItem As MailItem
    Dim strAttachmentName As String
    '
    ' Only inspect mail items
    ' Ignore appointments, meetings, tasks, etc.
    '
    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
        Debug.Print MailItem
        Set olMailItem = Item
        If olMailItem.Attachments.Count = 1 Then
            strAttachmentName = olMailItem.Attachments.Item(1).FileName
            olMailItem.Attachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile "C:\EmailAttachments\" + strAttachmentName
        End If
    End If
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set olMailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could do it this way-

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim olInboxItems As MAPIFolder
    Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient

    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objOwner = ns.CreateRecipient("xx@xx.com")
    Set olInboxItems = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = olInboxItems.Items

    'Debug.Print ns
    'Debug.Print objOwner
    'Debug.Print olInboxItems
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        SaveAttachment Item
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub SaveAttachment(olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim strAttachmentName As String
    '
    ' Only inspect mail items
    ' Ignore appointments, meetings, tasks, etc.
    '
    'Debug.Print MailItem

    If olMailItem.Attachments.Count = 1 Then
       strAttachmentName = olMailItem.Attachments.Item(1).FileName
       olMailItem.Attachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile "C:\EmailAttachments\" + strAttachmentName
    End If

    Set olMailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the variable as Items, but you assign it to an instance of the MAPIFolder object.
Change that code to

```
Set olInboxItems = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox).Items
```

Comment: When I set olInboxItems to the above I get a 'Run Type Error 13' 'Type Mismatch'.

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry identified the problem - Contradictory declarations.

The underlying issue is the misuse of

```
On Error Resume Next
```

[" It is very important to remember that On Error Resume Next does not in any way "fix" the error. It simply instructs VBA to continue as if no error occured."](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

and the non-use of

```
Option Explicit
```

You might have found.

```
Dim olInboxItems As Items
Set olInboxItems = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox).Items
```

rather than

```
Dim olInboxItems As MAPIfolder
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I actually had Option Explicit set originally but was getting an error. This I understand now was caused by not declaring Dim olInboxItems as Items.